# MUI: Black shadow around the MUI Menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am testing a MUI drawer to display some comments of a page. But when clicking on the menu, I can see some dark shadow around it.

[image: menu with shadow]

##### Code to display the menu of comments in drawer view:

```
export default function PageComments() {

  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorElUser);

  const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {

    if (event.type === "keydown" && event.key === "Tab") {
      return;
    }
    setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
  };  

}

return (
    <div>
      {["right"].map((anchor) => (
        <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
          <Drawer
            anchor={anchor}
            open={state[anchor]}
            onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
          >
            <Box
              sx={{ width: { xs: "300px", md: "450px" } }}
              role="presentation"
            >
              <div className="app">Responses({commentsWithDetails.length})</div>
              <Divider />
              {commentsWithDetails.map((comment, i) => {
                return (
                  <div className="comment" key={i}>
                    <Stack
                      spacing={1}
                      direction="row"
                      padding="5px"
                      display="flex"
                      justifyContent="space-between"
                    >
                      <div
                        style={{
                          display: "flex",
                          alignItems: "center",
                          flexWrap: "wrap",
                        }}
                      >
                        <PersonRoundedIcon sx={{ color: "#1e8e3e" }} />
                        <Stack sx={{ marginLeft: "2px" }}>
                          <span className="comment-author">
                            {comment.commentedBy}
                          </span>
                          <span className="time">
                            {comment.formattedCreateDate}
                          </span>
                        </Stack>
                      </div>

                      <IconButton
                        onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}
                        sx={{
                          p: "1px 1px",
                          cursor: "pointer",
                          blockSize: "20px",
                          borderRadius: "5px",
                        }}
                      >
                        <MoreVertIcon sx={{ fontSize: "medium" }} />
                      </IconButton>
                      <Menu
                        sx={{
                          mt: "25px",
                        }}
                        id="menu-space-page"
                        anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
                        anchorOrigin={{
                          vertical: "top",
                          horizontal: "right",
                        }}
                        keepMounted
                        transformOrigin={{
                          vertical: "top",
                          horizontal: "right",
                        }}
                      >
                        <MenuItem
                        // onClick={() => handleEditComment("edit")}
                        >
                          <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>
                            Edit
                          </Typography>
                        </MenuItem>

                        <MenuItem
                        // onClick={() => handleDeleteComment("delete")}
                        >
                          <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>
                            Delete
                          </Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Menu>
                    </Stack>

                    <span className="comment-text">
                      <div
                        className="c1"
                        modelValue={comment.description}
                      />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </Box>
          </Drawer>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Seems like its trying to open the multiple menu some how. Not sure at which part its trying to render multiple times even though other objects are working fine and showing properly including comments.

If the page is having one comment, then its showing properly. But if its having more than one comments, then the black shadow coming up as mentioned in the above image.

Comment: Your `Menu` is inside the `map()`, so you get 1 menu per iteration, and it looks like they will all be opened with the same `open` state, so I imagine it's exactly what you described, they all open at once. Using an `open` value that's an ID or an index and then setting `open={ open === index or id }` would resolve this.

Comment: I tried adding this for the Menu, but now its not able to open the Menu atall. Do I need to make any other changes ?

Comment: Wherever you set the open state, you will need to set it to one of the values you're using to identify the menu, other than that it should work. If not, then it would be worth adding a more complete example to your question, without seeing the entire component there's not a lot we can do to answer this fully.

Comment: @DBS, I have added the code snips from the main function where I am using open.

Comment: Take the menu off the map

Comment: Thanks @Mario. Taking Menu off the map worked. Earlier I had tried that but by mistake I was taking the icon too out of the map which was going out of the card.